How is free energy in thermodynamics related to free energy in information theory/neuroscience?
Background
In thermodynamics, free energy refers to either Helmoltz ($U - TS$) or Gibbs ($H - TS$) free energy, the quantity that is minimised at equilibrium in a closed system maintained at constant [T and V] or [T and p] respectively. It is called free energy because because it is "the energy that is 'free', available to do work in an idealized reversible process" [1].
In information theory, free energy is associated with negative variational free energy $\mathcal{L}$ (AKA evidence lower bound/ELBO), which refers to a lower bound on the log model evidence $\log (p(x))$, and is also central to the Free Energy Principle (FEP) in neuroscience [2]. The ELBO can be derived as follows (the inequality for the KL divergence follows easily from the fact that $\log(x) \le x - 1$):
$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{KL}[\;q(z|x) \;\Vert\; p(z|x)\;] &= \mathbb{E}_{q(z|x)}\left[ \log \left(\frac{q(z|x)}{p(z|x)}\right) \right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}_{q(z|x)}\left[ \log \left(\frac{q(z|x)p(x)}{p(x, z)}\right) \right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}_{q(z|x)}\left[ \log \left(p(x)\right) \right] - \mathbb{E}_{q(z|x)}\left[ \log \left(\frac{p(x, z)}{q(z|x)}\right) \right] \\
&= \log \left(p(x)\right) - \mathbb{E}_{q(z|x)}\left[ \log \left(\frac{p(x, z)}{q(z|x)}\right) \right] \\
&\ge0 \\
\Rightarrow \quad \log \left(p(x)\right) &\ge \mathbb{E}_{q(z|x)}\left[ \log \left(\frac{p(x, z)}{q(z|x)}\right) \right] \\
&= \mathcal{L}
\end{aligned}
$$
Question
Various sources (EG the Wikipedia page "Evidence lower bound") state that the variational free energy is "related" to the thermodynamic free energy, without stating what the relation actually is. So, how is the negative variational free energy $\mathcal{L}$ related to any/all of:

The expressions $U - TS$ or $H - TS$? (I see that the definition of $\mathcal{L}$ can be split up into an expected log joint term and an entropy term, but the entropy term is not multiplied by the temperature, and I don't see how the expected log joint term is related to the internal energy or enthalpy)
The quantity that is minimised at equilibrium in a closed system with certain properties (T and V, T and p) held constant? (okay, we could say that the ELBO is maximised because often we actively decide to do so [3], but this is not a good argument, because by the same argument we could call anything which we choose to minimise a "free energy")
The energy that is available to do work in an idealized reversible process?

References
[1] Kondepudi, Dilip, and Ilya Prigogine. Modern thermodynamics: from heat engines to dissipative structures. John Wiley & Sons, 2014.
[2] Friston, Karl, James Kilner, and Lee Harrison. "A free energy principle for the brain." Journal of physiology-Paris 100.1-3 (2006): 70-87.
[3] Kingma, Diederik P., and Max Welling. "Auto-encoding variational bayes." arXiv preprint arXiv:1312.6114 (2013).
